# Jsoup body() includes unwanted text

Tags: html, jsoup

Suppose I have an HTML document like:

```
This is not body<body>
This is body
</body>
```

Calling doc.body().text() returns:

```
This is not body This is body
```

Is there a way for me to separate these two texts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to parse this text as XML rather than HTML.

```
String html = 
        "This is not body<body>\r\n" + 
        "This is body\r\n" + 
        "</body>";
Document document = Jsoup.parse(html, "", Parser.xmlParser());
System.out.println(document.body().text());
```

returns `This is body`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you see is correct due to the leniency of the html spec, and browsers must still be lenient enough to do a best-effort to support bad markup from the early days of the web.

You can use [XmlTreeBuilder](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/parser/XmlTreeBuilder.html) to "parse XML without any of the HTML DOM rules being applied to the document."

The jsoup online demo has this option to test: https://try.jsoup.org/~KHbtVb7vli8fKNGtd9jIl6TK6xA